# What is the use of oracle first_Value analytical function?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a query which has first_value() as a analytic function.

```
SELECT 
    product_id, 
    product_name,
    list_price, 
    FIRST_VALUE(product_name) 
     OVER (ORDER BY list_price) first_product,
     category_id
FROM 
    ot.products
WHERE 
    category_id = 1;
```

The output I got was:
[image]

Here I got 70 rows.

So,I tried new query as:

```
SELECT product_id, 
       product_name, 
       list_price 
FROM   ot.products 
WHERE  category_id = 1 
ORDER  BY list_price;
```

The output I got is:

[image]

In this query I again got 70 rows.So,I am not understanding what is the use of fisrt_value() in the first query?Since the data I am getting is same what is the use of this analytical function?

Comment: It shows the first product name; thus the one with the lowest list price for all records.  IT's not limiting rows, it simply puts the same value on every row based on it's order in a list of prices.  the 'Intel Core i7-5930K' being the cheapest.  Put another way.  This query seems to return all processors; and then lists  the "Cheapest" on every record for possibly a comparison?  Also note in your first query you have column "First Product" not in second and all it's values are the product_name of the cheapest product in the result set.  As we don't know requirement; can't say why...

Comment: ok thank you got it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**So,I am not understanding what is the use of first_value() in the first query?**

Well, it's simply listing the cheapest product on every record in your result set in the column called "First Product"

**Since the data I am getting is same what is the use of this analytical function?**

But it's different.  you have a "First product column" in your first query.  Maybe someone's using it for a comparison later on.  Maybe it's to quickly link to the cheapest product within the result set later.... Can't say WHY someone coded it this way; but I can come up with a few guesses.

Note that 'Intel Core i7-5930K is the cheapest product in the result set; and thus gets listed on every other record in the result set due to the analytical function use.